# Unit Testing in xcode(Using GHUnit and OCMock)

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, installation, ocmock, gh-unit

In xcode,I am trying to do unit Testing using GHUnit and OCMock as described here :

[Unit Testing Xcode](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-quick-start-guide#otherlinks)

And Set Up methods as descibed here :

[GHUnitTestCase](http://gabriel.github.io/gh-unit/Classes/GHTestCase.html#overview)

But got the error in this method

> - (void)setUpClass { }

when I initialize my ViewController Object as below :

```
#import <GHUnitIOS/GHUnit.h>
#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>
#import "RS_LoginRSViewController.h"

@interface SampleLibTest : GHTestCase
{
  RS_LoginRSViewController * login;
}
@end

@implementation SampleLibTest

// Run before each test method
- (void)setUp { }

// Run after each test method
- (void)tearDown { }

// Run before the tests are run for this class
- (void)setUpClass
{
 GHTestLog(@"Log with a test with the GHTestLog(...) for test specific logging.");
 login = [[RS_LoginRSViewController alloc]init];
}

// Run before the tests are run for this class
 - (void)tearDownClass { }

// Tests are prefixed by 'test' and contain no arguments and no return value
 - (void)testA {
 GHTestLog(@"Log with a test with the GHTestLog(...) for test specific logging.");
 }

 // Override any exceptions; By default exceptions are raised, causing a test failure
  - (void)failWithException:(NSException *)exception { }
 @end
```

But got error as Apple Mach-O Linker Error :

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RS_LoginRSViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in SampleTestCase.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

But when I remove line

```
     login = [[RS_LoginRSViewController alloc]init];
```

from

```
- (void)setUpClass
```

method then It runs successfully.Why I am getting this error ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That error suggests that RS_LoginRSViewController is not being / has not been compiled for the simulator. Do your tests run successfully on a device?

Comment: @Ben Flynn : I resolved errors by adding frameworks and library to build phases..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved errors by adding necessary files , frameworks and library to build phases of project target of testing.